# Google Cloud DNS - What does the PTR record actually do?

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

In my business, my physical sever has an external IP of `123.123.123.123`. Performing a reverse lookup on that IP will give you `mail.myserver.com`. I had to ask my web host to create that PTR record for me.

In my Google Cloud, I have a VM, say the IP is 200.200.200.200. In the Cloud DNS, I can add a PTR record, but the options look like this:

[image: screen shot]

The redacted part is myserver.com.

So what does this mean? I create a reverse lookup that isn't reverse at all????

When using my favourite query tool (mxtoolbox.com), the PTR does not change from the default. The command `PTR:200.200.200.200` gives `123.456.789.101.bc.googleusercontent.com`

I've read that VMs in Compute Engine can't have PTRs on their IPs, so what does this PTR option do???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used for delegation. You would need to have your web host create a `CNAME` record that looks very much like a traditional `PTR` record (i.e. 200.200.200.200.in-addr.arpa.), but points to a `PTR record` in Google (i.e. the name you specify in the first input). The `PTR resource record` at Google would then point to an `A record` at Google as well (i.e. the name you specify in the second input). Then when someone tries to resolve your IP address to a `PTR record`, through redirection it resolves to the appropriate `A record` hosted by Google as expected.

> PTR (pointer) records map the IP address of a host to the canonical
>   (true) domain name for a host (address-to-name mapping). Known as
>   reverse DNS lookup, the IP address is written in reverse and appended
>   with the Address and Routing Parameter Area (arpa) top-level domain.
>
> PTR records are used as a security device and anti-spam measure; mail
>   and other types of servers can do reverse DNS lookups to verify the
>   identities of hosts.
>
> Usually, you will not manage PTR through Google Domains, because they
>   need to be set by the owner of your IP address block (generally your
>   ISP). Different IP block owners have different procedures for you to
>   request these records. Please contact your provider for more
>   information.
>
> Google Domains supports PTR records that reside in the DNS zone
>   corresponding to the your domain, for the purposes of having your ISP
>   create CNAME records that delegate to us the responsibility for
>   reverse lookups of those specific addresses.
>
> If your provider delegates a PTR record to you, your provider will
>   create a CNAME record that points to a PTR record that you manage
>   through Google Domains. For example, suppose your server's A record
>   looks like this: www     A     1h     111.222.33.4
>
> To delegate the PTR record to you, your provider must set the
>   following CNAME. Note that the order of the 4 numbers comprising the
>   IP address have been reversed:
>   4.33.222.111.in-addr.arpa.    CNAME     1h     ptr_www.example.com.
>
> In Google Domains, you would set the following PTR record: ptr_www
>   PTR     1h     www.example.com.
>
> Once these records are set, requests to reverse-lookup the IP address
>   111.222.33.4 will first go to your provider's record for 4.33.222.111.in-addr.arpa., which redirects to your record for ptr_www.example.com., which tells the requester that 111.222.33.4
>   corresponds to www.example.com.
>
> As a similar example for IPv6 addresses, if your server's AAAA record
>   looks like this: www     AAAA     1h     202:db80:1:2:3:4:567:89ab
>
> then its fully-specified IPv6 address is
>   0202:db80:0001:0002:0003:0004:0567:89ab. To obtain the CNAME record
>   that your provider must set, reverse this address (digit-wise,
>   ignoring the colons), putting dots between every digit and appending
>   .ip6.arpa. (including the trailing dot):
>   b.a.9.8.7.6.5.0.4.0.0.0.3.0.0.0.2.0.0.0.1.0.0.0.0.8.b.d.2.0.2.0.ip6.arpa.
>   CNAME     1h     ptr_www.example.com.

(Source: https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3251147?hl=en)